# Access locally stored Images in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

Currently I am developing an application, where the images downloaded from server has stored locally (MyApp/Images/image1.jpg).
Images are stored as an array. First Image getting displayed successfully, however other two images not shown, a black screen is coming. But from folder  i can access all 3 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to many solutions, I found simple safe apply does the work.

```
if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
       $scope.$apply();
}
```